# solana getParsedAccountInfo returns null in value

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I have this test wallet:

```
% solana account 9AYXoP3b22KHRhVuvjZbynpjNd2SXKFLoC1jrPMkyFkS

Public Key: 9AYXoP3b22KHRhVuvjZbynpjNd2SXKFLoC1jrPMkyFkS
Balance: 12.98943736 SOL
Owner: (removed by me)
Executable: false
Rent Epoch: 248
```

And I have this javascript snippet:

```
const SOURCE_TOKEN_ACCOUNT = new PublicKey('9AYXoP3b22KHRhVuvjZbynpjNd2SXKFLoC1jrPMkyFkS');

    const sourceInfo = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(
        SOURCE_TOKEN_ACCOUNT,
    );


console.log('tok ', sourceInfo);
```

When I run, I get this output:

```
tok  { context: { slot: 191644 }, value: null }
```

I would like to note that I'm trying to get this to function with multiple accounts. They all have the same slot value.

I want to know why value would be coming back `null.` I have nothing to go on with why this would be happening. I just want some value to show up. Since I don't know what is supposed to show up when this works, I don't know what value is should be, short of showing some sort of SOL. All I know is, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accounts in Solana store lamports (SOL) and data, and in this case, your account only has SOL in it, and no data, which is why the `value` is coming up as `null`.  For example, the token program at `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA` will also show the bytes of the data in the account along with the balance:

```
$ solana account TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Public Key: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Balance: 1.08999168 SOL
Owner: BPFLoader2111111111111111111111111111111111
Executable: true
Rent Epoch: 161
Length: 156480 (0x26340) bytes
0000:   7f 45 4c 46  02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   .ELF............
.... rest omitted for length ....
```

If you want data inside your account, you must allocate data to it, assign it to a program, and use a transaction on the program to modify the data.

I would highly recommend reading up more on how accounts work: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts

Comment: Well, thank you for that. I'm using some library to try NFT stuff, and it's requiring the data. Now I have to figure out how to add this data... one step at a time.